# Scroll text over an image in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to scroll my content into this board. How to do this?
Link to the image in which i want text to be scrolled : [IMAGE](http://s14.postimg.org/z0bjc6vht/boarlad_1.png)

I want that the text should be only in board section.

I tried the following code:

```
<style>
    #test { background: url("image/board.JPG") no-repeat top center fixed;
background-size: cover;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;}    
</style>

<div id="test">
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
     test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
   test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>


</div>
```

Comment: Make it background, define the container, place some text in it. What have you tried?

Comment: I have updated my code in question.. Please tell me how to bring the text in the board.. and scroll it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test_parent">
<div id="test">
 test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
 test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>
  test test test test test test test test test test test <br/>


 </div>

</div>


 #test_parent { 
  background: url("http://s14.postimg.org/z0bjc6vht/boarlad_1.png") no-repeat top center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 275px;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 145px;
```

}

```
   #test{
    width: 321px;
    height: 175px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid;  
 }
```